# Failure to build a commit in gitlab(gradle)

Tags: android, gradle, gitlab, build.gradle, gitlab-ci

When I commit and push changes to gitlab,assembly falls with an error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':somebible-id-client-app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ': somebible-id-client-app:_secondaryDebugApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve ru.somebible.android:statistic:0.0.5.
     Required by:
         project :somebible-id-client-app
      > Skipped due to earlier error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 22s
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'http://jenkins01.mobile.somebible.ru:7700/nexus/content/repositories/somebible-internal/'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://jenkins01.mobile.somebible.ru:7700/nexus/content/repositories/somebible-internal/'
    }
    google()
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.somebible.somebibleidclientapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            useProguard false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        prod {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Id Client App"
        }
        secondary {
            applicationId "ru.somebible.somebibleidclientappsecondary"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Id Client Secondary App"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    dependencies {
        ext.support_version = '25.3.1'

        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

        compile project(':somebible-id')
        apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$ext.support_version"
        compile "com.android.support:design:$ext.support_version"
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.3'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
        compile 'com.hannesdorfmann.mosby:mvp:2.0.1'
        compile 'com.annimon:stream:1.1.2'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

        compile 'ru.somebible.android:statistic:0.0.5'

        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

And most importantly, there is no such process, even without the prefix ApkCopy. That is, to see what the problem is locally impossible, since locally there is no such process and locally everything works. Direct please in the right direction.

Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle is trying to download the artifact `ru.somebible.android:statistic` but fails to do so because it can't find it in any known artifact repository. I assume that the artifact is published in this repository: `'http://jenkins01.mobile.somebible.ru:7700/nexus/content/repositories/somebible-internal/'`

In that case, make sure that your build machine has access to this repository and make sure that that artifact can actually be found in that repository.

Comment: Thank you! Your guess was right. My colleagues spoiled the place where the library was stored ..